# how to use ng2-chart.js directive in angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-template, ng2-charts

I've installed ng2-charts using npm

`npm install ng2-charts --save` and `npm install chart.js --save`

then added below into index.html

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
```

and then added below to app.module.ts
    import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

```
imports: [
   ChartsModule
]
```

but I'm getting ZoneAwareError while checking in console, I'm using angular 2.4.1 version. What is the correct way to install charts.js into angular 2? Surprisingly, despite chart.js being so popular, I didn't found neither documentation about its installation in angular2, neither a simple example of its usage there.

Comment: Are you using webpack or system.js?

Comment: system.js  @mikegeyser

Comment: Have you added any charts or new code onto the page? On a minimum test example, it just works for me - sorry. :(

Comment: as i have said after compilation ..i'm getting zoneawareerror ..when i check in console....@mikegeyser

Comment: can u tell  me how did u do .....

Comment: I did exactly what you did. :(

Comment: Can you check if the order of scripts is : require('core-js/shim');
require('zone.js'); and not require('zone.js');
require('core-js/shim`);

Comment: I had to add `map: { 'ng2-charts':'node_modules/ng2-charts/bundles/ng2-charts.umd.min.js'}` to the systemjs.config.js file to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The [installations steps](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts#installation) you did are correct!

Please refer to this following [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7fGsiuRjcF0M0Ffeoml2?p=preview) that describes a working version of ng2-charts with SystemJS.

.

Your component should look like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CHART_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES],
  styles: [`
    .chart {
      display: block;
    }
  `],
  template: `
    <base-chart
      class="chart"
      [datasets]="datasets"
      [labels]="labels"
      [options]="options"
      [chartType]="'line'">
    </base-chart>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private datasets = [
    {
      label: "# of Votes",
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
    }
  ];

  private labels = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'];

  private options = {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  };
}
```